# Need to find only first href of each product

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to get only the first href of each product.
Can someone give me a hint? Now i get more than one href of each

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.roco.cc/'



headers = {
     'UserAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
    }

productlinks = []

for x in range(1,30):
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives.html?p={x}&verfuegbarkeit_status=41%2C42%2C43%2C45%2C44')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='item product product-item')
    
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])

print(len(productlinks))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives.html?p={}"


productlinks = []
for p in range(1, 3):  # <--- increase number of pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(p)).content, "html.parser")

    for li in soup.select("li.product-item"):
        productlinks.append(li.a["href"])

print(len(productlinks))
```

Prints:

```
48
```

---

Then:

```py
print(*productlinks, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/62200-br-64-steam-locomotive.html
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/63280-dampflok-0310-der-db-mit-altbaukessel-in-stahlblauer-farbgebung.html
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/63281-dampflok-0310-der-db-mit-altbaukessel-in-stahlblauer-farbgebung.html
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/69281-br0310-express-train-steam-locomotive.html
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/63255-keine-anderung-der-dome.html
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/69255-dampflok-935-ac.html
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/63256-935-12-series-steam-locomotive-of-drg---1-%cc%81d1-%cc%81h2-design.html
https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives/69256-935-12-series-steam-locomotive-of-drg1%c2%b4d1%c2%b4h2-design.html


...and so on.
```